# right way to push files to remote repo

Tags: git

I'm trying to convert an existing folder with some files into a local repository and add a remote repository. Now the changes I make to the local repository has to be pushed to the remote repository.

I'm trying to follow the below code:

```
git init
git remote add origin <remote-url>
git fetch origin mainline
```

what's next?

note: Local repo has lot of other files which I don't want to push to remote repo. Files in Local repo and remote repo may not be in sync.

I only want to push to mainline and not create a new branch( say master).

Comment: Did you commit any files?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you added remote as origin.
so to proceed from there.

First create branch named mainline using

```
 git checkout -b mainline
```

Then add the files only that you want to push to mainline using and and you can use multiple times to add different files.

```
git add filename
```

once you finished adding all the files now write good commit message which will be displayed on mainline, using

```
git commit -m "Your message"
```

after this run

```
git push origin <yourmainlinename>
```

Comment: Just tried that and getting error: 
    `git push origin mainline`
"error: src refspec mainline does not match any"

Comment: @testuserme what's your mainline name? maybe it's master right? then push using ```git push origin master```

Comment: If I do that.. then in the remote repo it will create another branch named "master".
But I want to push the changes to the remote branch named "mainline"

Comment: then first create mainline using ```git checkout -b mainline``` and then follow the above steps I have describe in my answer.

Comment: after adding the remote repo. I fetched all the branches and then used `git checkout mainline`. I threw me error "error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:"

Comment: Somehow, git checkout -b mainline works. What is the difference?

Comment: ```git checkout -b``` will create a new branch on your local and checkout. and ```git checkout``` just checkout to existing branch

Comment: @testuserme if my answer worked for you then feel free to upvote and accept it !!

Comment: after `git checkout -b mainline` I tried adding few files, then commit them and used `git push origin mainline`.. this is throwing me an error `hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again. See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`

Comment: use ```git push --force-with-lease origin mainline```

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: `remote: To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected.
remote: Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the 'Note
remote: about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
To <remote repo>
 ! [remote rejected] mainline -> mainline (pre-receive hook declined)`

Comment: use ```git push --force origin mainline``` make sure this will overwrite your local changes to your remote mainline branch.

Comment: same error from my above comment: `remote: To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the 'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details. To <remote repo>  ! [remote rejected] mainline -> mainline (pre-receive hook declined)`

Comment: do ```git pull --rebase``` and then push

Comment: tried `git pull origin mainline --rebase` and got `error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:`

Comment: do ```git add .``` this will add the untracked files and then do ```git commit -m "Your message"``` and do git push

Comment: will `git add .` consider the `.gitignore` file and filter the unwanted files?

It was running for a long time, so I assume it is also tracking the files that should be ignored.

Comment: in .gitignore I have only excluded .txt and .json.. but the command `git add .` is running for a long time. Where as `git add *.txt *.json` will complete soon.

Comment: No git add . Should also finish soon because it just add files to staging.

Comment: Even after committing the `git add.` updates, it is throwing the same error for `git push --force origin mainline`

Comment: `git pull origin mainline` throws `warning: There are too many unreachable loose objects; run 'git prune' to remove them.
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`

Comment: what I would suggest to avoid going into more issue I would simply suggest to checkout to master using ```git checkout master ``` and then do ```git pull``` then do ```git branch -D mainline```and then follow exactly the same as I have describe in the answer section. because you messed something so I would recommend going this way